# Find three greatest numbers of an array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, max

I need to know how I can find the three greatest numbers of an array. Currently I can only find the greatest number of an array, but I want to have the three greatest of it:

```
$avg = array();
$avg[20,10,30,50,80,90,220];
echo max($avg);
```

Maybe you can help me by this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// The array
$avg = [20,10,30,50,80,90,220];
// remove duplicates if any
$avg = array_unique($avg);
// sort in descending order
rsort($avg);
// get the first three elements
$avg = array_slice($avg, 0, 3);
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/386524)

Comment: You just beat me on it for a few seconds :)

Comment: I was hoping for a one-liner but that `rsort()` gets you every time :)

Comment: thank you...that works! :) now i got it. can you may tell me how i can find the three lowest numbers too?

Comment: @johny just change rsort() to sort()